# How to redirect some ip's in django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I thought I stumbled on an answer to this question but now I cannot find it. I am looking to redirect some ip's in my production environment so that all ip's that are not mine will direct to a coming soon type of page.

Any ideas of how to make this happen?

Using nginx/gunicorn just in case it has to be done on that end.

Comment: I want all IP's except mine to be redirected to a specific page/view/place basically to allow my ip free roam over the site and limiting everyone else to one page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx Ip Whitelist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917866/nginx-ip-whitelist)