# HipChat Server login screen limit

Tags: hipchat

Is it possible to restrict access to the HipChat Server login screen for some networks for security reason?

I need to limit only to site root.

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser, not StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not feature right now to allow you to do that directly.

One way you could work around it is to write an script that updates the ngixn configuration to add IP filtering. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917866/nginx-ip-whitelist) proposes a method to achieve something similar to what you describe (you would need to customize the script to fit into HipChat Server's nginx configuration though):

```
cat /var/www-allow/client1-allow.conf
allow 192.168.1.1;
allow 10.0.0.1;

cat /etc/nginx/sites/client1.conf
...
server {
    include /var/www-allow/client1-allow.conf;
    deny all;
}
```

Try the script manually. Once it works, move the script to /home/admin/startup_scripts/ipfilter (keep the file without extension, and make it executable), so that your configuration stays after reboot and upgrade (/home/admin/startup_scripts contains a few examples of different scripts).