# How to restrict ip access in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I want to restrict access by IP for specific php file in Nginx reverse_proxy.
so in my virtual host path `/etc/nginx/sites-available/sub.mydmn.com` I have the following configs:

```
server {
    server_name wwww.sub.mydmn.com sub.mydmn.com;
    root /home/mydmn/;

    access_log off;

    # Static contents
    location ~* ^.+.(png|mp4|jpeg)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    # Limit IP access
    location = /mine.php {
        allow <MyIP_Here>;
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # Dynamic content, forward to Apache
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}

# Deny server with IP access!
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
    return 403;
    }
}
```

But when I start the server, Nginx blocks all IPs for `mine.php`.
What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917866/nginx-ip-whitelist

Comment: @RogertheShrubber I don't need white list, I want to allow access `mine.php` only with 1 IP address in reverse_proxy,

Comment: You should replace the `return 404` with the four `proxy_` statements from the other `location` block.

Comment: @Richard Smith Thanks a lot. would you please create full answer to be clearer for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx chooses a single `location` block to process a request (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)). Your `location = /mine.php` block, not only returns a 403 status if the IP address is denied, but also returns a 404 status if the IP address is allowed. You need the request to be handled by the service on port 8080 if the IP address is allowed.

One solution is to duplicate the statements from the `location /` block.

For example:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $host;

location = /mine.php {
    allow ...;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Note that `proxy_set_header` statements can be moved into the outer block so that they are inherited by both blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for details.

Comment: Excellent!!, That's perfect